# Car'ing procedures from lists

Tags: scheme, racket

Given a simple list say '(+ 1 2) I am trying to simply evaluate the expression. But it doesn't seem to think the car of the list is a procedure.

```
(define i '(+ 1 2))
> i (+ 1 2)
(procedure? (car i))
> #f
(procedure? +)
> #t
(car i)
> +
(apply (car i) (cdr i))
; apply: contract violation
;   expected: procedure?
;   given: +
;   argument position: 1st
; [,bt for context]
```

I was wondering if there is a way to take the car and use it as a procedure or if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `'(+ 1 2)` is short for `(list '+ '1 '2)`.
This means the first element of the list is the symbol `'+` and not
the procedure bound to `+`.

You can write:

```
(define i (list + 1 2))
```

Instead.

Alternatively, you can use quasiquote and unquote:

```
(define i `(,+ 1 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `(car '(+ 1 2))` evaluates to the *symbol* `'+`, not the *function* represented by `+`. When you create a list using `quote`, none of the elements are evaluated.

The easiest way to fix this is to use `list` to create your list instead of `quote`. Since `list` is a function, it evaluates its arguments:

```
scratch.rkt> (define expr (list + 1 2))
scratch.rkt> (car expr)
#<procedure:+>
scratch.rkt> (apply (car expr) (cdr expr))
3
scratch.rkt> ((car expr) 3 4)
7
```